# Regex Match specific text and date in this format: MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, .net, regex

.net regex:

Using this to match any date MM/dd/yyyy:

```
(?=\d)^(?:(?!(?:10\D(?:0?[5-9]|1[0-4])\D(?:1582))|(?:0?9\D(?:0?[3-9]|1[0-3])\D(?:1752)))((?:0?[13578]|1[02])|(?:0?[469]|11)(?!\/31)(?!-31)(?!\.31)|(?:0?2(?=.?(?:(?:29.(?!000[04]|(?:(?:1[^0-6]|[2468][^048]|[3579][^26])00))(?:(?:(?:\d\d)(?:[02468][048]|[13579][26])(?!\x20BC))|(?:00(?:42|3[0369]|2[147]|1[258]|09)\x20BC))))))|(?:0?2(?=.(?:(?:\d\D)|(?:[01]\d)|(?:2[0-8])))))([-.\/])(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\2(?!0000)((?=(?:00(?:4[0-5]|[0-3]?\d)\x20BC)|(?:\d{4}(?!\x20BC)))\d{4}(?:\x20BC)?)(?:$|(?=\x20\d)\x20))?((?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?::[0-5]\d){0,2}(?:\x20[aApP][mM]))|(?:[01]\d|2[0-3])(?::[0-5]\d){1,2})?$
```

But what need to match is this:

```
Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];MM/dd/yyyy
```

Where: **Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];** is always the same.

I tried prepending that static text to the regex but it doesn't work.

How to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that is a hairy regex.  Why is it so complicated?

Comment: It's what I could find that worked.

Comment: Can you give an example of the candidate string? I think your RegEx is way too complicated.

Comment: this is the candidate string: Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];MM/dd/yyyy ... the date can be any date but the text prior to it including the semicolon is static. and I need regex because this is fragment of a larger piece of text and I need to pick this out of that.

Comment: You may have forgotten to escape the "[" characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't work as you forgot to Escape the regex pattern which is very much important.

You can try the following:

```
var subject = "Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];12/14/2014";
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];")+ @"(?<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})");
var match = regex.Match(subject);
if(match.Success)
{
    var datePart = match.Groups["date"].Value;
    DateTime dt;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(datePart,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        //In the right format, and also a valid date.
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing I need to match a fragment of text in a file: blahblah;mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @user167908 Your question doesn't says that anywhere. Edit your question with required info. Some sample input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: of course it does! "But what need to match is this:

Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];MM/dd/yyyy"

Comment: @user167908 Sorry I overlooked it, So you need to match static text `Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];` followed by `MM/dd/yyyy` format datetime?

Comment: @user167908 Updated my answer, take a look

Answer (score 3):

What about this, without using regex:

```
var str = "Package.Variables[User::ProcessStartDateInput].Properties[Value];12/10/2009";
var datePart = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(";") + 1);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datePart, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Assuming your string always has the same format (date following `;` and nothing after it)

Regular expressions are a bit overkill for static text. This is easier to maintain and most likely performs better.

Comment: It should be a TryParse, not a ParseExact.  Otherwise I agree with you.

Comment: Personally I prefer the `FormatException` when the string is always supposed to be in the correct format.

Comment: This was a Regex, he doesn't know it if matches or not.

Answer (score 0):

This regex would match the pattern and capture the date.  You can use .NET functions to validate the date, if required.

```
Package\.Variables\[User::ProcessStartDateInput\]\.Properties\[Value\];(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})
```